# Excel 2013 table formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-office-2013

I currently have a table that looks like this:

```
Company | 2013 Total | 2013 Gross $'s | 2013 Gross % | 2012 Total | etc..
        |            |                |              |            |
```

Obviously this is not a sustainable format for data. 
I would like to reformat it (possibly using a **pivot table**?) to look more like this:

```
              | 2013 | 2012 | 2011 |
Company Name  |      |      |      |
   Total      |      |      |      |
   Gross $'s  |      |      |      |
   Gross %    |      |      |      |

Company 2     |      |      |      |
   Total      |      |      |      |
   Gross $'s  |      |      |      |
   Gross %    |      |      |      |
```

Fairly similar to [this example at microsoft.](http://officeimg.vo.msecnd.net/en-ca/files/728/754/ZA103462989.png)

I tried modifying some of the examples in the above link, by making multiple tables with ID keys to create relationships in a pivot table but I was unable to get the desired outcome.

When trying to create a pivot table using multiple tables I tried with the following:

```
Table 1 (names)    Table 2: (years)
   |                 |
| Company nm |    | Year  |
| comp 1     |    | 2011  |
| comp 2     |    | 2012  |
                  | 2013  |

Table 3 (values)
   |
| Company | Year | Total | Gross |
| comp 1  | 2011 | xxx   | xxx   |
| comp 1  | 2012 | xxx   | xxx   |
| comp 1  | 2013 | xxx   | xxx   |
| comp 2  | 2011 | xxx   | xxx   |
```

The Name from the Company column was a row, the years were set as columns, and the total/gross from values were set as a value in the pivot table.

The relationships:

1. values (company) -> name (company)
2. values (year) -> years (year)

If i only use the Totals and not the Gross, it looks similar to what i want: http://prntscr.com/32dsm9 , but if i add the gross field: http://prntscr.com/32dsu8 It adds a bunch of columns. I'm not sure how to make that be a row.

Comment: what do your tables look like?

Comment: @mcalex: Which tables? I have posted what the data currently looks like. Did you want to see what the tables looked like when I tried to do the Pivot relationship?

Comment: yep, that's what i meant.  Did Ken L's solution work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, sorry that I don't have Excel 2013 so I demonstrate with Excel 2007 but they should be similar.

Click on the PivotTable you have created, at **Column Labels** at the **PivotTable Field List** of the right panel, you will see a "(Sigma) Values" button if you are to summarize over one field.  Simply drag it to **Row Labels** area (as the two figures below).

[image: Values at Column Labels area]

It will look like this afterwards:

[image]

For further formatting choices you can explore PivotTable Tools -> Design -> Layout.

---

**Extra - PivotTable with conditional formatting**

To highlight a cell if the totals have gone down since the last year:

Click on one of the cells to apply the highlight condition (e.g. B6 as above figure), select **Home** > **Conditional Formatting** > **New Rule**.  Select Apply Rule To "All cells showing "Sum of Total" values for "Company" and "Year"; Select rule type **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**; at Format values where this formula is true input `=B6>C6` (`B6` is the cell you selected and `C6` is a relative reference); change the format (e.g. fill with yellow colour) as this figure:
[image: Conditional formatting settings]

Final outcome looks like this:
[image: PivotTable with highlight]

Comment: This worked. Is there any way to highlight a cell if the totals have gone down since the last year?

Comment: Revised my answer to show the way to highlight the cell.